# Splitting a List into three different list

Tags: python

I want to separate the main list into three different lists.

For instance, I have

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I want to separate it into the following list:

```
b = [1, 4, 7, 10]
c = [2, 5, 8, 11]
d = [3, 6, 9, 12]
```

How should I go about it? I have no idea at all how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly do you want to split the list? There's many ways to split a list, this would help narrow down a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slices indices in lists

```
L2 = L1[begin_index:end_index:step]
```

where `begin_index` can be omitted if it is 0 and `end_index` can be omitted if you want to go up to the end of the list.

In your case,

```
b = a[0::3]
c = a[1::3]
d = a[2::3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using slicing:

```
b, c, d = a[0::3], a[1::3], a[2::3]
```

Or with a comprehension:

```
v = 3
b, c, d = [a[i::v] for i in range(v)]
```